# Css overflow not working with Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, overflow

The .css file

```
 #log{
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    padding-top: 20px;
    overflow: scroll   ;
    height: 150px;
    color: #23568a;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;

    }
```

In the html file, 
I am using the log like this

```
 <div id="receiveBox">
        <h2>Receive </h2>
        <div id="log"></div>
    </div>

socket.on('my_response', function(msg) {
                $('#log').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('Received #' + msg.count + ': ' + msg.data).html());
            });
```

Using
overflow: scroll   ;
i tried to add scroll to the results it will split out but the scroll bar only appears in Safari and Chrome and not in Firebox. 
How do i make it  work in firefox ??

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: The link is just a possible solution which should or should not be implemented. I have posted the question above

Comment: **ALL** the code should be in the question to demostrate the issue.

Comment: Should i include my whole .css file ?

Comment: Nope, just enough to demonstrate the issue. A **minimal** demo is required.

Comment: Provide fiddle link

Comment: @Paulie_D I edited the question. Does the question make sense now ?

Comment: @user3260487 I edited the question. Does it make sense now ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (after commenting back/forth):

To make it automatically scroll down the div when new data is added, add this piece of code to your js right after the `socket.on`:

```
socket.on('my_response', function(msg) {
  $('#log').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('Received #' + msg.count + ': ' + msg.data).html());

  //New
  $("#log").animate({scrollTop: $("#log").prop("scrollHeight")}, 'slow');
});
```

Updated jsfiddle with hard-coded new data adding (ignore the `.html()` stuff, that is just example):

https://jsfiddle.net/82h4a5d9/24/

---

Kumuda,

I personally do not have experience with this part of your code:

```
socket.on('my_response', function(msg) {
    $('#log').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('Received #' + msg.count + ': ' + msg.data).html());
});
```

But after taking a look at just the HTML and CSS, and testing in Firefox with some dummy data, it looks like it was just the flex-direction causing issues. Try it without that?

So just comment out this piece:

```
/* flex-direction: column-reverse; */
```

https://jsfiddle.net/82h4a5d9/3/

Comment: The scroll bar does come thank you. But I need to go to the bottom of the page. Right now, I have to scroll down. Any way it goes down automatically ?

Comment: So you want it to continuously scroll down as the data loads (ending up at the bottom of the page once all data is loaded)?

Comment: Yes go down as the data is entered

Comment: Do you want the box to be fixed height with scrollbar inside or just to have all the data show going down the page with scrollbar for the whole page? EDIT: I see that you have "height: 150px", so likely you want fixed height?

Comment: No i want to box to be of fixed height. It should not go down the whole page.

Comment: Check the EDIT: section of my post now, that should be all you need

Comment: For some reason does not work. Do i need to add something else also ? or just the one line

Comment: Interesting... You should just need to add that one line, as long as you didn't change anything else. Are you getting any errors? (I edited it again to show where you would put it, if you put in wrong place)

Comment: No I’m not getting any error. It is just not scrolling down. I added the line in the right place

Comment: Im not seeing any data now. There is only one message so nothing to scroll.

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't be scrolling, the jsfiddle is working fine. Try adding some more data and see if it does?

Comment: Yes i got it. Apparently my JQuery was not up to date. Thank you so much !!

Comment: Sweet! Happy to be of service

Comment: Hello the scroll bar is going down whenever a new notification comes. If the user is scrolled up and a new notification comes, it scrolls down automatically. Is there a way to prevent that ? If the user scrolls up, it should go down manually not automatically. How can i implement this ?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply on this, I could not think of a solution and got very busy. Thinking of it again, you would likely need to have an on scroll event for the div, and have a check for which direction the scroll went. Then, if the scroll Direction was upwards, you could stop the execution of the automatic scroll down. Beware, as the jQuery auto scrolling will also fire the on scroll event, so that's why you have to only do it for scrolling upwards. There are plenty of questions regarding scroll Direction so just check one of those. Hope that helps